# How to configure settings.py for mongodb ?

Tags: python, mongodb

I created django web app that use mongo database , I connet to mongo with pymongo

```
 def load_database():
    mongo = pymongo.Connection('127.0.0.1')
    db = mongo['database']
```

when I tried to load my web app , I get error

```
Exception Type:

ImproperlyConfigured



Exception Value:

settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details. 


Exception Location:

Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py in complain, line 15
```

it looks that settings.py is wrong configured , here is my settings.py :

```
MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or     
'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
 # The following settings are not`enter code here` used with sqlite3:
'USER': '',
'PASSWORD': '',
'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or   '
'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
}
}
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong  ? when I load homepage that don't coneect to mongo , only static files it loads fine , when I click on buttom on hoempage that gets data from mongo database and print out that data , I get this error .  Also I tried python manage.py syncdb but gets error : ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE   value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Answer (score 2):

For proper working of mongoDB you should install these packages:
Django-nonrel,
djangotoolbox,
mongodb-engine for Django.

And after that you can edit settings

```
DATABASES = {
   'default' : {
      'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
      'NAME' : 'my_database'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pymongo directly, you can just leave out the entire `DATABASES` variable from settings.py.

If you don't want to use pymongo directly, consider looking into [mongoengine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/django.html).

Comment: I use pymongo diretly but it looks that problem is not in pymongo, I just figure our it now, I use  request.session , so that is why I get error, to use seasion variable I need to syncdb database , do you know how to do it  ?

Comment: OK you need to specify a database backend to store the session data.  You can use MongoDB for this using [Mongoengine (see section 6.4)](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django.html#sessions).

Comment: when I add in my settings.py  SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions' , i get error  ImportError
Exception Value:  

No module named mongoengine.django.sessions

Comment: can someone check my settings. py , here is link where I upload it http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1376987235

Comment: I can't run python manage.py syncdb   and use seassion variables ?

Comment: error that i get when run manage.py syncdb  is ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't installed mongoengine? Also you don't need to do `python manage.py syncdb` as far as I know.